# Issue in extracting gz files in Linux

Tags: linux

I have downloaded the following file on my Linux computer:

```
wget https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/input/ncdc/all/1901.gz
```

I tried to unzip the file using gunzip 1901.gz but it did not work. I check the file format using 'file' command and it says:

```
1901.gz: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

I am quite new to Linux. May I know how can I successfully extract the data for usage?

Answer (score 1):

You have downloaded a regular HTML file and you called it `something.gz`, hoping that that would turn it into a zipped file, but this is not how it works: your file is not a zipped file, so there's no reason trying to unzip it.

Comment: may i know how to extract the data from it?

Comment: Google just told me you might use `htmlq` for this :-)